# Dynamic Memory Allocated is always deleted?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case, dynamic-memory-allocation

I do not understand, I have a switch statement that presents the users to create dynamically allocated memory, display all lists, and lastly delete them (case 3, which is printed below.)

When I select case 3 in the program and enter anything other than 'y' or 'Y' it STILL deletes the list and I do not understand why...

If any can help me out here, I would really appreciate that:

```
    case 3:
        cout << "Which list did you want to delete?" << endl
            << "List: ";
        cin >> i;
        i--;
        if (dynArray[i] == NULL){
            noListExist();
            break;
        }
        else
            printoutAllLists(dynArray[i], arraySize[i], i);
            cout << "Are you sure? ('y' or 'n'):" << endl
                << "Confirm: ";
            cin >> j;
            if (j == 'y' || 'Y'){
                delete[] dynArray[i];
                dynArray[i] = NULL;

            }
            else
                break;

        break;
```

Comment: `if (j == 'y' || j == 'Y')` is the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need {...} after the first else to define the extent of the else statement.  As it stands there is only one line in your else statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (j == 'y' || 'Y')
```

is always true, since the right hand side of `||` i.e. `'Y'` is a non-zero, which gets evaluated when `j` is not equal to `'y'`

Use :

```
if (j == 'y' || j== 'Y')
```

<sub>There might be some more errors, and chances of memory leaks too</sub>

Comment: I do not think I have any memory leaks (I tried to keep it simple) but I do have this problem with user input... If the user inputs a special character into an int variable, it causes infinite looping... Ex. User inputs ' * ', into an int variable it will cause the following while loop to iterate indefinitely.